# Missing Outlook 2013 Add-in

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, outlook

I am working on making a Outlook Add-in for Outlook 2013. The issue is, I use Visual Studio 2010. I did some googling and found that I need the Developer Tool Kit and it lead me [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217). I installed the tool kit, but I am still not seeing any new Templates. What am I doing wrong, or what can I do to get that Outlook Add-in?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately VSTO allows creating version-specific add-ins. VSTO 2010 (Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime) is shipped with Visual Studio 2010 Professional edition or above. It supports creation and editing of document- and application-level add-ins for Office 2007 and Office 2010. You need to use later Visual Studio versions for creating COM add-ins for Office 2013. However, you can run solutions in Office 2013 that were created in earlier Visual Studio versions, see [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.